# Shortcut for "{}" and "()" in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter

Does anybody know of a way to create a keyboard short-cut for inserting a set of `{}`'s and `()`'s in TeXnicCenter?

I have looked into defining my own Text Modules in the Insert tab, but this still requires me to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd> to insert the "number 6" Text Module (my own). I am looking for something shorter; a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657007/shortcut-for-and-in-texniccenter?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of customization, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It is a Windows-based [TSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_and_Stay_Resident) application that runs in the background and is activated based on certain keystroke scripts.

<sub>If you know the AutoHotkey interface, skip over this section...</sub>

---

AutoHotkey bases a keystroke sequence `<ks-seq>` on its own scripting language and replaces the keystroke combination with some other set of actions `<actions>` and sends it to the active window. In short, the syntax used (and stored in a file `AutoHotkey.ahk`, say) is set of expressions of the form

```
<ks-seq>::<actions>
```

Here is a list of some of the available commands/keystrokes (taken from [AutoHotkey "Send" command documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)):

- `!`: Sends an <kbd>Alt</kbd> keystroke. For example, `Send This is text!a` would send the keys `This is text` and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. Note: `!A` produces a different effect in some programs than `!a`. This is because `!A` presses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and `!a` presses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. If in doubt, use lowercase.
- `+`: Sends a <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keystroke. For example, `Send +abC` would send the text `AbC`, and `Send !+a` would press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.
- `^`: Sends a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keystroke. For example, `Send ^!a` would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, and `Send ^{Home}` would send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>. Note: `^A` produces a different effect in some programs than `^a`. This is because `^A` presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and `^a` presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. If in doubt, use lowercase.
- `#`: Sends a <kbd>WIN</kbd> keystroke, therefore `Send #e` would hold down the Windows key and then press the letter <kbd>e</kbd>.

---

<sup>...and start reading here again.</sup>

As such, you could define the hotkeys

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (short for `p`arentheses) using `^!p::Send ()`; and
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (short for `b`races) using `^!b::Send {{}{}}`. Note the grouping required for successfully sending `{` and `}`.

This is what `AutoHotkey.ahk` would look like:

```
; IMPORTANT INFO ABOUT GETTING STARTED: Lines that start with a
; semicolon, such as this one, are comments.  They are not executed.

; Ctrl+Alt+b -> {}
^!b::Send {{}{}}
; Ctrl+Alt+p -> ()
^!p::Send ()
```

You could append `{Left}` to each command, which would move the cursor back one spot to between `()` or `{}`, if need be. Changes to hotkeys can be made on-the-fly, as long as you 
"reload the script" before using it.